# Optimizing parameters using CVParameterSelection in Weka Explorer

Tags: weka

What I am trying to accomplish is to optimize one parameter at a time, for one learning algorithm. Take for example Ridor and lets say I want to optimize the number of folds (-F) parameter and run it from 2-10 or whatever. I then want output on a format that is easy to parse and then choose a final value myself. I think this should be possible with CVParameterSelection. Even if not I would like help to get it to work on at least a basic level.

I have selected CVParameterSelection as my classifier, and as a parameter to CVParameterSelection I have chosen Ridor as the classifier to optimize. What I have trouble doing is telling CVParameterSelection that it is the -F parameter I want to optimize, and I want to go from 2 to 10 in 1 increments on the format 2 10 9 as per instructions here http://weka.wikispaces.com/Optimizing+parameters. The choice of Ridor and parameter here is completely arbitrary. I want to run any algorithm, with any parameter and have it vary the parameter in a range.

I can not find the ArrayEditor that this tutorial speaks of, I have clicked literally everything everywhere. Nothing that looks like an array editor, nothing that is named ArrayEditor. The total command line per default is weka.classifiers.meta.CVParameterSelection -X 10 -S 1 -W weka.classifiers.rules.Ridor -- -F 3 -S 1 -N 2.0.

I have tried sending -F 2 10 9 on the command line to both CVParameterSelection and Ridor. I have also tried reading section 11.5 on optimizing performance in the Weka book but I do not understand the instructions there either.

This feels like it should be really simple and obvious. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong and post a detailed description of exactly how to do this. Please assume I am a total idiot because it really should not take many many hours to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During your configuration of CVParameterSelection, you will find field named "CVParameters", by clicking it, new window named "weka.gui.GenericArrayEditor" will open. Write inside it your parameter and its range as showing in weka tutorial, finally close this window.